# Client program response with http request

Tags: java

Update: Thanks @MartinFrank for the idea, I added the http header to the result, and it works.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
>  Content-Type: text/html
>  Content-Length: result.length()

---

I am working on a client program to work with the web application. the web server application will send a 'get' request to the client. then the client program will start to listen to the COM port which connected with a scale device and return the result weight as string back to the web server application.

I try to test the program with sending request with ARC client

> http://localhost:8083/test

the system able to print

> Listening for connection on port 8083 .... 
>           Just connected to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50346
>       GET /test HTTP/1.1
>       HOST: localhost:8083
>    result ???  3 741g

but the request is keep hanging on the requesting stage without response result like the picture below:

[ARC client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqQdm.png)

any idea to get the proper response from the client program ? Thanks for the help.

```
  static public void main(String[] args)
{

    ServerSocket server;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(8083);
    System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8083 ...."); 
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (!line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            String result = openConnection();.//listen to COM port and return weight result.
            var pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.print(" result ???  "+result);
            pw.println(result);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

```
   public static String openConnection()
{
    if(comPort == null || !comPort.isOpen()) {
        comPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[0];
        comPort.setComPortParameters(2400,7,SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT,SerialPort.EVEN_PARITY);
        comPort.openPort();
        System.out.println("COM port open: " + comPort.getDescriptivePortName());
    }else {
        System.out.println("COM port already open: " + comPort.getDescriptivePortName());
    }
    while(fullWeight == null) {
        fullWeight = getWeight();
    }
    return fullWeight;

}
```

Also tried to hard code the result and remove the port functions.

```
  static public void main(String[] args)
{
....
            //String result = openConnection();
            String result = "OK"; 
            var pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            pw.println(result);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide 'openConnection()'  code also?

Comment: i think you totally hit the spot @Anuradha the COM operations are most likely blocking methods. I have written java code for COM ports and know it from that times. (even though it's been a while, a looooong while) ^_^

Comment: @MartinFrank thanks for the idea, i have tried to hard code the result and remove the COM ports functions, still no luck.

Comment: one thing that came into my mind: did you close the client connection after you have send your answer?

Comment: @MartinFrank i tried to add `clientSocket.close()` after `pw.println(result);`  and it shows `'The requested URL can't be reached
The service might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

The response status "4" is not allowed. See HTTP spec for more details: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6.1.1'`

Comment: i think you do not reply in a proper way. see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6 how the format of the response **has to be**. It is more than just a `String` of `result ??? 3 741g`

Comment: maybe you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Server_response to get an working example

Comment: @MartinFrank Thank you, i added the http header in the response and it works.

Comment: very nice that you got your code working!!! thanks for being part of that journey!

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to flush your PrintWriter to effectively send your respone

```
pw.println(result);
pw.flush();
```

Comment: since the OP mentioned in the comments that the response **is received** it is not a 
 very likely that the problem lies by the writer. Furthermore it is mentioned from the OP that the client cannot handle the response properly. The OP even mentions the problem with the response

Comment: @MartinFrank from my understanding the response is not received. The OP states the request is hanging and provides a printscreen showing  a request without any data. If you're thinking, like your comment seems to indicate, that "result ??? 3 741g" is the received result then on my side i think it is only some string printed to the console. The OP mentions the COM response is received not the http one. I would be glad if the OP could check this solution and give a reply

Comment: @MartinFrank @Mumrah81 i tried both solution. First for adding flush, it will shows `The requested URL can't be reached. The response status "56" is not allowed` the perfect solution is adding the http headers  in the result.